# Elegant Python loop for parsing flat XML

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, for-loop, lxml

I am parsing an XML file in Python3 using lxml.objectify:

```
<root>
    <object_header></object_header>
    <object_details></object_details>
    <object_details></object_details>
    <object_header></object_header>
    <object_details></object_details>
    <object_header></object_header>
</root>
```

Note that sometimes the object does not have attributes.

The way I am currently parsing this (which works but is inelegant) is by the following:

```
from lxml import objectify, etree
root = objectify.parse(xmlFile).getroot()
elems = [el for el in root.iterchildren()]
# data is list of objects
data = []
# Have to instantiate outside of for loop in case last object has not details.
objectDetails = ''
# Don't store first object right away.
firstObject = True
# Iterate through each XML element.
for elem in elems:
    if elem.tag == 'object_header':
        # Remember object header info.
        object = storeHeaderInfo(objectDetails)
        # Skip saving if first object, need to grab object details.
        if firstObject == True:
            # Don't skip again, in case object has no details.
            firstObject = False
            continue
        # Save object, already grabbed object details.
        data.append(object)
    else:
        # Process object details in <object_details> tag.
        objectDetails += etree.tostring(elem)
# Save last object.
object = storeHeaderInfo(objectDetails)
data.append(object)
```

What I don't like is how I have to code storing the object twice. Once for each object in the for loop, and then again for the last object.

Is there a more pythonic or elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make things simpler if you would use the [`following-sibling::*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) expression:

```
from lxml import objectify, etree    

root = objectify.parse("input.xml").getroot()
elems = root.xpath("//object_header")

for elem in elems:
    header = elem.text
    objectDetails = ''
    for sibling in elem.xpath("following-sibling::*"):
        if sibling.tag == 'object_header':
            break

        objectDetails += str(etree.tostring(sibling))

    print(header, objectDetails)
```

Given the following input:

```
<root>
    <object_header>object1</object_header>
    <object_details>detail1</object_details>
    <object_details>detail2</object_details>
    <object_header>object2</object_header>
    <object_details>detail1</object_details>
    <object_header>object3</object_header>
</root>
```

The code would print:

```
object1 b'<object_details>detail1</object_details>'b'<object_details>detail2</object_details>'
object2 b'<object_details>detail1</object_details>'
object3
```